# css transparency effect cordova

Tags: html, css, cordova

I have a container `DIV` with a background image. Inside this div i have three divs with some text, what I want to achieve is the following:

The three div should be transparent with some color filter, so I have the background image with let's say a transparent red filter or any color.
my html is:

```
<div id="contenuto">
    <div id="schermata1">
        <h3 >Schermata soggetti</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="schermata2">
        <h3>Schermata due</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="schermata3">
        <h3 >Schermata tre</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
.filter{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.filter:before{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="contenuto">
    <div id="schermata1" class="filter">       
<h3>Schermata soggetti</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="schermata2" class="filter">      
<h3>Schermata due</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="schermata3" class="filter">        
<h3>Schermata tre</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/2/)**

Comment: i tryied  with opacity attribute...but in this way the text i have the text trasparent...even if i set the attribute opacity:1 for the text